# Как обработать большой массив без прерывания потока в JS, используя setTimeout?

Tags: javascript, массивы, многопоточность, асинхронность

Есть массив на +10000 элементов ссылок. Каждую итерацию ищется совпадает ли элемент по ссылке и удаляется, если да. В итоге выходит около 4 млн итераций и фризы.

Я пытался разбить массив на подмассивы и обрабатывать их через каждые 200 миллисекунд, но стали удалятся все элементы. Как можно разбить выполнения массива на части без прерывания потока?

```
let slicedarray = sliceIntoChunks(listDeletes, 30); // разбитие массива

for (let i = 0; i < slicedarray.length; i++) {
  setTimeout(function() {
      for (let j = 0; j < slicedarray[i].length; j++) {
          document.querySelectorAll(`.pcVideoListItem a[href^="${urlSiteCrop(listDeletes[i][j])}"`).forEach(e => e.closest('li').remove());
      }
  }, 200);
}
```

P.S
Работает, если поставить setTimeout на внутренней цикл, но 1 миллисекунда это слишком много и в итоге все начинает мелькать из-за изменения страницы рывками.

```
for (let i = 0; i < listDeletes.length; i++) {
  setTimeout(function () {
    document.querySelectorAll(`.pcVideoListItem a[href^="${urlSiteCrop(listDeletes[i][j])}"`).forEach(e => e.closest('li').remove());
  }, 1);
}
```

Comment: хз, может просто потому что дом не предназначен для такого зверства?

Comment: Вам наверное сюда: https://habr.com/ru/post/151155/

Comment: Возможно, стоит сначала изменить алгоритм. Сначала собираете массив всех элементов ссылок, чтобы вызвать querySelectorAll только один раз. Потом проходитесь по массиву элементов, сравнивая их адреса с массивом адресов. При совпадении, добавляете во второй массив совпавших. Пока мы не производим изменений в DOM, поэтому нет перерисовок. И уже в конце удаляете все элементы из второго массива с совпадениями. Если всё равно будет медленно и глючно, уже в этот алгоритм вставлять асинхронность.

Comment: @vsemozhebuty неплохая идея, не помню почему сделал вызов querySelectorAll, но совсем про это забыл, спасибо

Answer (score 1):

Спасибо @vsemozhebuty за подсказку. Функция была изначально некорректна. Эта работает гораздо быстрее, что асинхронность не понадобилась.

```
  function delBoxes() {
    let alllinks = document.querySelectorAll(`.pcVideoListItem .usernameWrap a`);
    let linksinclude = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < alllinks.length; i++) {
      if(listDeletes.includes(alllinks[i].href)){
        linksinclude.push(alllinks[i]);
      }
    }
     linksinclude.forEach(e=>e.closest("li").remove());
  }
```